# how to add list item through jquery in ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <ul id="content">
        <li>
            <label  class="desc">Album Title:</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text"  class="field text full required" name="album[title]" id="album_title"  />
                <?php echo form_error('album[title]', '<label class="error">', '</label>'); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label  class="desc">Image</label>
            <div>
            <input type="file">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="" id="add_row"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>skin/images/add.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="buttons">
                <button id="saveForm" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Submit" type="submit">Add</button>
        </li>   
   </ul>
```

i want to add new `<li>` before last `<li>` for add dynamic image field(through jquery).

Thanks in advance
Loganphp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [jQuery insertBefore() method](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

```
$('<li><input type="image" /></li>').insertBefore($('.buttons'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$('#content li').last().insertBefore("<li></li>");
```

In This way u can append many li before last li

**Updated**
U can also use this

```
$('#content li:last').insertBefore("<li></li>");
```

Comment: Isn't the syntax for `insertBefore()` different in that what you're inserting comes before the function call and the selector is a parameter to the function call?